# SQL LAG function returns wrong answer

Tags: sql

I have below question: for website_id = 1 and dates between May 15 and May 31, show each statistics row: day, clicks, impressions, conversion rate and the conversion rate on the previous day.Name the last column as previous_conversion.

Conversion rate = the number of clicks divided by the number of impressions, multiplied by 100

My code is:

```
select
    day, clicks, impressions,
    (clicks/cast(impres as float)) * 100 as "conversion rate",
    (lag(clicks/cast(impres as float)) over(order by day)) * 100 as "previous_conversion"
from
    statistics
where
    website_id = 1
    and day between '2016-05-15' and '2016-05-31'
```

It is saying its wrong answer.

Please let me know what's wrong here?

PFB the data:

```
id | day        | users | impres | clicks | revenue
---+------------+-------+--------+--------+--------
1  | 2016-05-14 | 27617 | 165702 |    407 |   85.50
1  | 2016-05-15 |  8563 |  59941 |    135 |   33.75
1  | 2016-05-16 | 33679 | 303111 |    609 |  121.73
1  | 2016-05-17 | 25123 | 175861 |    383 |   57.47
1  | 2016-05-18 | 32233 | 225631 |    594 |  118.75
1  | 2016-05-19 | 33504 | 335040 |    857 |  197.08
1  | 2016-05-20 | 10830 |  86640 |    229 |   52.58
1  | 2016-05-21 | 13904 | 152944 |    380 |   75.90
1  | 2016-05-22 | 35180 | 386980 |    992 |  168.68
1  | 2016-05-23 | 18911 | 283665 |    773 |  154.59
1  | 2016-05-24 | 19938 | 259194 |    553 |  121.58
1  | 2016-05-25 | 14796 | 192348 |    416 |   66.61
1  | 2016-05-26 | 20953 | 146671 |    298 |   59.50
1  | 2016-05-27 | 14756 | 191828 |    564 |   84.63
1  | 2016-05-28 | 20397 | 203970 |    645 |  135.55
1  | 2016-05-29 | 30382 | 182292 |    446 |   71.31
1  | 2016-05-30 | 39977 | 519701 |   1382 |  262.61
1  | 2016-05-31 | 34817 | 382987 |    796 |  230.90
```

[Image_of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OQOZ.png)

Comment: please tag with appropriate database

Comment: What are your results, and what is wrong with the results you get?

Comment: Besides a typo on impressions, I don't see anything wrong with the code above.

Comment: Floats can cause rounding issues. Are you able to use a numeric data type?

Comment: ANSI date literals need the keyword `DATE`, e.g. `and day between date '2016-05-15' and date '2016-05-31'`. Then, you probably want your result ordered, so add `order by day` to your query.

Comment: BTW: SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS used. Which are you using?